# Reload user groups without reboot and without ugly hacks for use in a bash script

Tags: bash, 22.04, sudo, users, groups

The `/etc/sudoers.d/user1` file contains:

```
%user1  ALL=(user1) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Which using the `sudo` command grants all users of the `user1` group (`%user1`) to login to the `user1` user (`ALL=(user1)`) without the need for a password.

If after adding the `user1` group to the current user `myuser`, a reboot is not performed, then using the sudo command it keeps asking me for a password to login to the `user1` user until the next reboot because the user groups are not reloaded.

In fact, if I run the `groups myuser` command, I get:

```
myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare user1
```

If instead I run the `groups` command, I get:

```
myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

without the group `user1`.

How do I reload user groups without reboot and without ugly hacks for use in a bash script?

I've already read the solutions proposed by the various StackExchange links ad nauseam, they don't satisfy me, as I want to remain in the same shell session during the reload or temporarily open a new one and close it again at the end of the command useful for reloading user groups, because everything is contained within a giant script.

I use `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit`.

Comment: Are you sure the issue here is about "reloading sudoers", and not about updating group memberships? Did the `user1` group exist already or did you just create it? If it was a pre-existing group, did you add the user with which you are testing the sudo command to it in the same session as that in which you updated the sudoers file?

Comment: I will try more combinations of things thanks to your comment, the fact remains that the script creates the user `user1` (therefore also the group of the same name), associates the current user to that group and then creates the file `/etc/sudoers.d/user1` in the same session.

Comment: AFAIK The only way to do this is to boot into the recovery kernel (From grub)

Comment: Yes, I confirm, it's a group update problem, in fact I tried to remove myself from the `user1` group, restart the computer and put me back in the `user1` group, then it asked me again for the password to login to the `user1` user. In fact, the specific problem is that the `groups myuser` command returns: `myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare user1`. With the `groups` command it returns: `myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare` without the group `user1`. How do I update groups?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo it's anything that starts a new *login session* I think - so for example `su - user1`

Comment: I've already read these solutions ad nauseam, they don't satisfy me, as I want to remain in the same shell session during the reload or temporarily open a new one and close it again at the end of the command useful for reloading user groups, because everything is contained within a giant script.

Comment: I completely twisted the question.

Comment: Is there no solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably going to attract unpleasant comments, but there is a way - after struggling to find a solution the conventional way, I asked ChatGPT. Here's what worked on my ubuntu 20.04 @MarioPalumbo:

- tried to restart the culprit, sudo.service, but `sudo systemctl status sudo.service` shows it's masked. `file /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service` answers `/lib/systemd/system/sudo.service: symbolic link to /dev/null`
- I deleted this pseudo-file, `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service`
- then created a `/lib/systemd/system/sudo.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Sudo Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo -i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then after a final `sudo systemctl restart sudo.service` I could run a `sudo -i` *from another fresh terminal* without being asked for my password.

I ended the a (probably useless) `sudo systemctl stop /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service`, then a final `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service && sudo ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to reset things properly.

I'm afraid this *is* a ugly hack, though...?

Comment: What does the sudo service have to do with reloading groups?
Should restarting sudo.service update newly added groups to a user? Are you sure?
If you're sure and have tested this thing, I'll give it a try.
Welcome to StackExchange. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I have a real clue about the link between reloading groups and sudo, @MarioPalumbo. I just know that I finally could sudo passwordless from Session2 after going through this on Session1.